# Rails app - extra record displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that allows users to add albums they like to a database. Anyone can then come along and write a review for that album. Pretty simple.

I am running into a problem where an extra record appears to be created for the reviews on each album's show page. Every album, even if it has not ever been reviewed, has an additional, seemingly empty review being displayed when I use .each to display each review in the album show page. I want to get rid of that.

Here is an image of the problem. I have used CSS to highlight reviews in red. As you can see, there is an empty review at the bottom. When I inspect the review in question, it's raty title is "Not reviewed yet!"

[image]

Here is my albums_controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :new, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @albums = Album.all
    if params[:search].nil?
      @albums = Album.all.order(year: :desc).order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 24)
    else
      @albums = @albums.where("albums.title || albums.year || albums.artist LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").order(year: :desc).order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 24)
    end
  end

  def show
     if @album.reviews.blank?
      @average_review = 0
     else
      @average_review = @album.reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
     end
     @review = @album.reviews.build
   end

   def new
     @album = Album.new
   end

   def edit

   end

   def create
     @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

     respond_to do |format|
      if @album.save
         format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @album }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @album.update(album_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @album }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @album.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to albums_url, notice: 'Album was successfully    destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

def set_album
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
end

def album_params
  params.require(:album).permit(:title, :artist, :year, :cover)
end
end
```

Here is the album show page, which is where the extra review is being displayed:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-md-push-3 col-xs-push-1 top bottom">
    <%= image_tag @album.cover, class: 'show_image' %>
    <h2><%= @album.title %></h2>
    <h4><%= @album.artist %></h4>
    <h5><%= @album.year %></h5>
    <p class="white">Average Review<div class="average-review-rating" data-score=<%= @average_review %>></div></p>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% if @album.user_id == current_user.id %> 
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_path(@album), class: 'grey' %> 
            | <%= link_to 'Delete', album_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'grey' %>
        <% end %> 
    <% end %>
    <br /><br />
    <h4>Reviews</h4>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <p class="grey">Write a review</p> 

        <%= form_for [@album, @review] do |r| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="rating-form">
                    <label>Rating</label>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= r.text_area :comment, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Write a comment" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= r.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
            </div>
        <% end %> 
    <% end %> 

    <br />
    <% @album.reviews.each do |r| %>
        <div class="red">
            <div class="review-rating" data-number="<%= r.rating %>">
            </div>
            <p class="white"><%= r.comment %></p>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <% if current_user.id == r.user_id %> 
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_review_path(@album, r.id), class: 'grey' %> |
                    <%= link_to 'Delete', album_review_path(@album, r.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'grey' %>
                <% end %> 
            <% end %>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>



<script> 
$('.review-rating').raty({
readOnly: true,
score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-number');
},
path: '/assets/'
});

$('#rating-form').raty({
path: '/assets/',
scoreName: 'review[rating]'
});

$('.average-review-rating').raty({
readOnly: true,
path: '/assets/',
score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score')
}
});
</script>
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and ask the silly question, have you checked your database to make sure you don't have an empty review in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is on the last line of your `show` method: `@review = @album.reviews.build`. This line not only creates a new `Review` instance and assigns it to `@review`, but it also adds that instance to the array in `@album.reviews`. So, in your view, when you iterate over `@album.reviews`, you will see all of the persisted reviews as well as the one new, not persisted review that was built with `build`.

The easiest way to fix this would be to add this line in your view:

```
<% @album.reviews.each do |r| %>
  <% next unless r.persisted? %>
```

Another solution would be to associate the new review with the album, but not on the `@album` instance. In the controller:

```
@review = Review.new(album: @album)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because of last line in `show`.

```
@review = @album.reviews.build
```

It builds an empty review.